# Render a jBuilder partial inside a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jbuilder

I'm trying to overwrite default to_json method in a model. There are numerous jBuilder partials for all models, named as the model does, but in snake case. So:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  json.partial! "charts/#{self.class.name.demodulize.underscore}"
end
```

But actually, I got a node in json, named "partial!" and a string as value.

How to render jBuilder partial inside a Rails model?

Comment: You simply don't do it. A model has nothing to do with views, is not his responsibility. What are you trying to achieve? Can you expand the context  so we can give you the correct solution?

Comment: @coorasse Thank you for your response. I understand how really bad this idea is, but I had to deal with it this way (big chunk of legacy code, hard to change anything) .
I am moving project from Rabl template engine to Jbuilder, and was stuck with just one dirty hack in a set of inherited models. Previous solution was as following: `ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(Rabl::Renderer.json(self, "charts/#{self.class.name.demodulize.underscore}", view_path: 'app/views'))`.
So, I am trying to create similar one for Jbuilder.

Answer (score 3):

As a disclaimer, this is a dirty hack. it's better to avoid such code.

```
  builder = JbuilderTemplate.new(ApplicationController.new.view_context)
  builder.partial!("foo/bar")
  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(builder.target!)
```